# Sparc T5240 ILOM password grief

Tags: sun, password-reset, sparc, lom

I'm trying to reset the ILOM root password on a SPARC Enterprise T5240.

Neither of the 2 methods described below work for me, so I'm after further suggestions (short of guessing the root password - I've been trying that!).

**Method 1 - Jumper J10401**

[Lost root password and ILOM config is reset using Jumper J10401 (short pins 1-2)](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/sunsparcenterpriset5140andt5240serverstechnicalpresentation-110904214604-phpapp02/95/sun-sparc-enterprise-t5140-and-t5240-servers-technical-presentation-40-728.jpg?cb=1315172892)

Some web sources suggest you may have to press the front panel Power button to power on the system to complete the reset.

But for whatever reason, nothing happens when I press that button (ie the system doesn't power up.  The SER MGT port still works, but only ILOM is powered)

**Method 2 - default user plus physical presence**

As per [ILOM 3.1 docs - Password Recovery for root Account](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24707_01/html/E24528/z400203c1534691.html)

I suspect the problem here is that this only works for ILOM 3.x, and the server is running 2.x?

Any suggestions gratefully received, including tricks to bypass ILOM completely and just boot Solaris?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? specifically the power button not doing anything?

Answer (score 1):

To reset using the jumper. You must remove all power/unplug. Move the jumper. Plug back in and wait 30 seconds or so...possibly longer on these beasts. press and hold the power button (10 seconds usually works), it will not power up. Release the power button, unplug, reset jumper. Plug back in and the Ilom pass should be reset. Default user/pass is root/changeme.

Hope this helps